# OpenJPA Transactions - Single or Multiple Entity managers?

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, openjpa, entitymanager

I have a `DBManager` singleton that ensures instantiation of a single `EntityManagerFactory`. I'm debating on the use of single or multiple `EntityManager` though, because a only single transaction is associated with an `EntityManager`.

I need to use multiple transactions. JPA doesn't support nested transactions.

So my question is: In most of your normal applications that use transactions in a single db environment, do you use a single `EntityManager` at all? So far I have been using multiple `EntityManager`s but would like to see if creating a single one could do the trick and also speed up a bit.

So I found the below helpful: Hope it helps someone else too.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions#Nested_Transactions

> Technically in JPA the EntityManager is in a transaction from the
>   point it is created. So begin is somewhat redundant. Until begin is
>   called, certain operations such as persist, merge, remove cannot be
>   called. Queries can still be performed, and objects that were queried
>   can be changed, although this is somewhat unspecified what will happen
>   to these changes in the JPA spec, normally they will be committed,
>   however it is best to call begin before making any changes to your
>   objects. Normally it is best to create a new EntityManager for each
>   transaction to avoid have stale objects remaining in the persistence
>   context, and to allow previously managed objects to garbage collect.
>
> After a successful commit the EntityManager can continue to be used,
>   and all of the managed objects remain managed. However it is normally
>   best to close or clear the EntityManager to allow garbage collection
>   and avoid stale data. If the commit fails, then the managed objects
>   are considered detached, and the EntityManager is cleared. This means
>   that commit failures cannot be caught and retried, if a failure
>   occurs, the entire transaction must be performed again. The previously
>   managed object may also be left in an inconsistent state, meaning some
>   of the objects locking version may have been incremented. Commit will
>   also fail if the transaction has been marked for rollback. This can
>   occur either explicitly by calling setRollbackOnly or is required to
>   be set if any query or find operation fails. This can be an issue, as
>   some queries may fail, but may not be desired to cause the entire
>   transaction to be rolled back.
>
> The rollback operation will rollback the database transaction only.
>   The managed objects in the persistence context will become detached
>   and the EntityManager is cleared. This means any object previously
>   read, should no longer be used, and is no longer part of the
>   persistence context. The changes made to the objects will be left as
>   is, the object changes will not be reverted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EntityManager`s by definition are not thread safe. So unless your application is single threaded, using a single EM is probably not the way to go.

Comment: a CLI based application is single threaded & Given that you don't invoke any Thread.start(), it that right?

Comment: So what one should do if an application should use lazy-loading in ajax, but also should merge changes made on those lazy-loaded entities?